# How to get next page url with phpQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, phpquery

I have custom HTML pagination template:

```
<ul class="number-list">       
    <li><a href="/article/" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="1">1</a></li>
    // Current page with class [.red]
    <li><a href="/article/?page=2" class="page-number js-page-filter red" data-page="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/article/?page=3" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/article/?page=4" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/article/?page=5" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="5">5</a></li>
    <li><span class="page-number">...</span></li>
    <li><a href="/article/?page=31" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="31">31</a></li>
    <li><a href="/article/?page=32" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="32">32</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can get current page url using this code:

```
$current = $doc->find('.number-list li a.red')->attr('href');
```

How I can get next page url in my case?

I tired:

```
$next = $doc->find('.number-list li a.red')->next('a')->attr('href');
$next = $doc->find('.number-list li a.red')->next('li a')->attr('href');
$next = $doc->find('.number-list li a.red')->next('.page-number')->attr('href');
$next = $doc->find('li a.red')->next('li a')->attr('href');
$next = $doc->find('li a.red')->next('li .page-number')->attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andreas. You can get all `<li>` and check if it `<a>` has class `red`.
This element will be your current, after that, you can get the next element.
Hope it helps you.

```
$document = phpQuery::newDocument('
<ul class="number-list">       
    <li><a href="/article/" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/article/?page=2" class="page-number js-page-filter red" data-page="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/article/?page=3" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/article/?page=4" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/article/?page=5" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="5">5</a></li>
    <li><span class="page-number">...</span></li>
    <li><a href="/article/?page=31" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="31">31</a></li>
    <li><a href="/article/?page=32" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="32">32</a></li>
</ul>
');

$lis = $document->find('.number-list li');
foreach ($lis as $li)
{
    if(pq($li)->find('a')->hasClass('red'))
    {
       var_dump(pq($li)->next()->find('a')->attr('href')); // get the next li and it a tag
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer ))